# Can someone explain how OpenXML works(in this SP)?

Tags: stored-procedures, openxml

I am looking at this tutorial

and it confuses me as I don't get the SP

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spTEST_InsertXMLTEST_TEST](@UpdatedProdData nText)
AS 
 DECLARE @hDoc int   

 exec sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT,@UpdatedProdData 

 INSERT INTO TBL_TEST_TEST(NAME)
 SELECT XMLProdTable.NAME
    FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, 'ArrayOfTBL_TEST_TEST/TBL_TEST_TEST', 2)   
       WITH (
                ID Int,                 
                NAME varchar(100)
            ) XMLProdTable

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hDoc
```

First I am using SQL 2005 and do I need to install something on the server to get OPENXML to work?  Next I don't get what these statements do

```
// not sure what @hDoc is for and why it is an int
 DECLARE @hDoc int   

 // don't get what this is and where the output is.
 exec sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT,@UpdatedProdData 

// don't get why it is "XMLProdTable" and if it always has to be like this
 SELECT XMLProdTable.NAME

// pretty muct don't get anything what is happening after OPENXML
 FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, 'ArrayOfTBL_TEST_TEST/TBL_TEST_TEST', 2)   
           WITH (
                    ID Int,                 
                    NAME varchar(100)
                ) XMLProdTable

// Don't know what this is really executing
EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hDoc
```

Thanks

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187367.aspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ms186918(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> // not sure what @hDoc is for and why
>   it is an int  DECLARE @hDoc int

**That will be used in the next call, it is an output parameter**

> // don't get what this is and where
>   the output is.  exec
>   sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc
>   OUTPUT,@UpdatedProdData

**It is calling the sp_xml_preparedocument, output just means it is an output parameter, @hDoc will be populated with the value in the proc**

> // don't get why it is "XMLProdTable"
>   and if it always has to be like this 
>   SELECT XMLProdTable.NAME

**XMLProdTable is the alias used in the next part, the CTE is named XMLProdTable**

> // pretty muct don't get anything what
>   is happening after OPENXML  FROM
>   OPENXML(@hDoc,
>   'ArrayOfTBL_TEST_TEST/TBL_TEST_TEST',
>   2)
>              WITH (
>                       ID Int,
>                       NAME varchar(100)
>                   ) **XMLProdTable --alias**

**It populates the CTE with values from the XML document under the ArrayOfTBL_TEST_TEST/TBL_TEST_TEST tag**

> // Don't know what this is really
>   executing EXEC sp_xml_removedocument
>   @hDoc

**This is releasing the document from memory**

Take a look at the samples here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186918.aspx

Comment: So what is this ArrayOfTBL_TEST_TEST/TBL_TEST_TEST tag? Like where do I change it? How does it get set? How about SELECT XMLProdTable.NAME, do I need to put one for each column in my table like XMLProdTable.NAME, XMLProdTable.QTY, etc?

Comment: And all that stuff really isn't needed, if you use the SQL Server 2005 native XQuery support (@xml.query(), @xml.nodes(), @xml.value() etc.)